# What Are The Best Error Handling Processes For a Stateless React Form Both Client & Server Errors?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, validation, graphql, material-ui

I added the entire component, being that I'm new to posting I figured more information was better than not enough. Basically where it stands the form is "stateless", other than using the state the form itself holds. I'm attempting to handle errors that will come from two angles. Client side errors like,
"Passwords dont match, "Not a valid email", ect. Those I'm attempting to use validator lib for. Second angle being server side errors. Currently the errors will come in from my mutation response. I'm hoping that I can find a smooth way to handle these errors without state, and currently I'll try to use handleChange function for client. If that's a bad approach or to data heavy please share your advice/wisdom. Also, any advice or better practice is greatly appreciated in the code, and in future posting. Thanks (Very new to Full Stack Development)

Imports

```
import React from 'react'
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
import { useMutation } from '@apollo/react-hooks'
import FormHelperText from '@material-ui/core/FormHelperText'
import validate from 'validate.js'
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl'
```

Material UI for styling

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  form: {
    width: '100%',
    marginTop: 15,
  },
  paper: {
    marginTop: 15,
  },
  register: {
    margin: 15,
    color: 'white',
    backgroundColor: '#414849',
    width: '95%'
  },
  email: {
    margin: 15,
    width: '95%'
  },
  username: {
    margin: 15,
    width: '95%'
  },
  password: {
    margin: 15,
    width: '95%'
  },
  confirmPassword : {
    margin: 15,
    width: '95%'
  }
})
```

Form Component

```
// need to access error elements, update errors from validator & from server
// and also reset errors either on resubmit, or handleChange
function Form (props){

  function handleChange(event, value){
    const name = event.target.name
    console.log(event.target.value)
  }

  async function onSubmit(props){
   var form = document.querySelector('form')
   var values =  validate.collectFormValues(form)
   console.log(form.email)
   console.log(form.querySelectorAll('p')[0])
    try{
     const results = await props.client
      .mutate({
        mutation: gql`
         mutation register
          ($userName: String!, $email: String!, $password: String!){
            register(userName: $userName, email: $email, password: $password){
              id
              userName
            }
          }`,
        variables: {
          userName: form.userName.value,
          email: form.email.value,
          password: form.password.value,
        }
      })
     console.log(results)
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }

  const classes = useStyles()
  return(
   <Container component="main" maxWidth="sm">
    <Paper className={classes.paper}>
      <form
        name='form'
        className={classes.form}>
        <TextField
          className={classes.email}
          name='email'
          variant='outlined'
          type='text'
          label='Email'
          InputLabelProps={{
            shrink: true,
          }}
          onChange={(event) => {
            handleChange(event)
          }}/>
        <FormHelperText
          name='emailError'
        >
          Future Email Error
        </FormHelperText>
        <TextField
          className={classes.username}
          name='userName'
          variant='outlined'
          type='text'
          label='Username'
          InputLabelProps={{
            shrink: true,
          }}
          onChange={(event) => {
            handleChange(event)
          }}/>
        <TextField
          className={classes.password}
          name='password'
          variant='outlined'
          type='text'
          label='Password'
          InputLabelProps={{
            shrink: true,
          }}
          onChange={(event) => {
            handleChange(event)
          }}/>
        <TextField
          className={classes.confirmPassword}
          name='confirmPassword'
          variant='outlined'
          type='text'
          label='Confirm Password'
          InputLabelProps={{
           shrink: true,
          }}
          onChange={(event) => {
            handleChange(event)
          }}/>
        <Button
          className={classes.register}
          variant='contained'
          onClick={()=> {
            onSubmit(props)
          }}>
          REGISTER
        </Button>
      </form>
    </Paper>
   </Container>
  )
}

export default Form
```

Comment: This question might be a bit too broad/opinionated for SO. However, you might take a look at some more popular libraries, like `formik` or `react-hook-form`, that make form validation easier.

Comment: I'll definitely take a look, appreciate the insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it all wired up at the moment and so far so good. I posted my solution below for anyone interested in critique or maybe it'll help solve your own issue.

inside onSubmit function.

```
var clientError;
   var form = document.querySelector('form')
   var values =  validate.collectFormValues(form)
   var errors = await validate(values, constraints)

   if(errors == undefined){
     clientError = false
   } else clientError = true

   resetErrors(form)
   handleErrors(form, errors || {})

   if(clientError == false){
     try{
     const results = await props.client
      .mutate({
        mutation: gql`
         mutation register
          ($userName: String!, $email: String!, $password: String!){
            register(userName: $userName, email: $email, password: $password){
              id
              userName
            }
          }`,
        variables: {
          userName: form.userName.value,
          email: form.email.value,
          password: form.password.value,
        }
      })
     console.log(results)
     props.props.history.push('/login')

    }
    catch (err) {
      handleGraphqlErrors(form, err)
    }
   }
  }
```

The actual functions for error handling

```
//handle return errors from mutation
  function handleGraphqlErrors(form, err){
    const graphqlErrors = err.toString().slice(22)
    console.log(graphqlErrors)
    if(graphqlErrors == 'Username is already taken'){
      document.getElementById('userNameError').innerHTML = graphqlErrors
    }
    if(graphqlErrors == 'Email is already in use'){
      document.getElementById('emailError').innerHTML = graphqlErrors
    }
  }

  //map errors to proper input fields
  function handleErrors(form, errors){
    Object.keys(errors).map((key, index) => {
      console.log(errors[key])
      document.getElementById(`${key}Error`).innerHTML = errors[key]
    })
  }

  //reset error input fields to blank
  function resetErrors(form){
    var errorInputs = form.querySelectorAll('p')
    Object.keys(errorInputs).map(key => {
      errorInputs[key].innerHTML = ''
    })
  }
```